# I am using this code to crop an image using open CV ,But this error keeps coming

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, computer-vision

I am using the following code  to crop an image . when I print the cropped,Its showing and empty array. Could anyone help me to get this cropping done right

```
import cv2
import pytesseract


image = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Ramesh\Desktop\Parsing_Project\Resumes_jpg\Akhil\output1.jpg')
image = cv2.resize(image,(800,740))

cropped = image[292:37, 564:65]

cv2.imshow("cropped",cropped)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: This is the error screenshot]

Comment: You've failed to read in the image. Try doing     print(image) after the imread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you read an image with OpenCV Python you get a Numpy array. Cropping from this array (it's called [slicing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) with Numpy) does not work that way. You do not define start and length, but start and end point:

```
cropped = image[start_row:end_row, start_col:end_col]
```

Be aware that the end row/col itself are exclusive so not included. What you get with your example is of course an empty array which is impossible to display with OpenCV.

Comment: What I did was trying to crop using the coordinates.  Is there anyway to pass coordinates and crop ?

Comment: By coordinates you mean x/y and width/height? It is as easy as it can get:  `image[y:y+height, x:x+width]`.